# Installing CXF with Eclipse 3.5

Tags: eclipse, installation

As per http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user/reference/preferences.html

The CXF 2.x preferences can be accessed via  `Window > Preferences... > Web Services > CXF 2.x Preferences` from the top level menu.

but I dont see the option `CXF 2.x Preferences` under Web Services, though I have chosen JavaEE perspective.

any ideas how to enable this?
Sorry for such a simple question.

I also cannot do not see CXF as a Project Facet as per http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.doc.user/gettingstarted/requirements.html

I know this is something to do with getting Eclipse aware of CXF libraries, but cant find the tutorial for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CXF tooling is not present in Eclipse 3.5 "Galileo" release. It was added in Eclipse 3.6 "Helios". You cannot upgrade in place from one major release of Eclipse to another. You will need to download a new Eclipse distro. I recommend Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers package that you can get from the [official download site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

Answer (score 11):

Go to Help -> Install New Software. In the drop down 'Work With' select : 
**The Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) Project update site - http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates**

In the 'type filter text', type in 'cxf' and select the SDK and other results and install them. Restart Eclipse and you should get `CXF 2.x` Preferences under `Window > Preferences... > Web Services`

Answer (score 2):

If CXF runtime is not showing up in the Preferences, try updating the WTP version for your Eclipse installation.

Point to http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/, update the plugins and restart Eclipse.