# Apache CXF 2.x option doesn't appear under Web Services in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, web-services, apache, cxf, eclipse-indigo

In Eclipse under Window > Preferences > Web Services, all the tutorials I've seen show an option for Apache CXF 2.x. From there, they add the runtime, etc. and start working on web services. My issue is that the Apache CXF 2.x option does not show up under Web Services and I don't know how to make it appear. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545030/installing-cxf-with-eclipse-3-5) is a similar SO question. However, in that question the version of Eclipse was different and the accepted answer was to get Java EE Developers package.

I have Eclipse for Java and Report Developers 1.4.1.20110909. The reporting package, according to the [Compare Eclipse Packages page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php), should contain all the same features as the EE developers package (plus a couple more). Please correct me if I'm wrong. But, if I'm right, then why is the Apache CXF 2.x option not showing up under Web Services? How do I get that option in there? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely need to install the CXF Web Services plugin to WTP.   Go to the "Install New Software" thing in eclipse and search for CXF.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I had tried that before and got an error about missing plugins. With more investigation, I found that I also was missing some server adapters from JST. So, I installed the server adapters and then the CXF plugin, and now I have the option for CXF 2.x Preferences. Your answer helped get me on the right path, so I'll mark it as accepted...with this comment, maybe others with the same problems can resolve it easier.